# WPF Styles - Creating Font template

Tags: .net, wpf, styles

I'm creating a resources file to be used in our new WPF application.
I can create Colour templates as follows:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BorderColorBrush" Color="Black"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationBorderColorBrush" Color="#FF26425D" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBorderColorBrush" Color="#FF59593E"/>
```

but how do i do the same for fonts? ie: a base type font family?

Thanks  in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create your own font, I think WPF could not help to you. But if you want all labels and text was in one format, you could use `Style` for the Control and TextBlock:

```
        <Window.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Control">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Courier New" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Courier New" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </Style>
        </Window.Resources>
```

Because of `TextBlock` is not a child class of `Control`, you should do it twice. (Correct me if its wrong)

Comment: Manage to do this way  <FontFamily x:Key="FontFamilyDefault">Ariel</FontFamily>
    <System:Double  x:Key="FontSizeDefault">11</System:Double>